# How to run the PowerShell batch file or a command.ps1 file through SQL server if sql is in one sever and file is in another server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I want to connect two VM/server one has data file and batch file another have sql install wanted to trigger command of server A which will hit server b files

Sql command--- in server A

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell  'cd.. && "C:\Program Files\Powershell\6\pwsh.exe" -File "C:\Users\sprasad\Desktop\script\command1.ps1"'
```

error are

> 1- import-module: The specified module 'C:\Program
>   Files\Derivation_19_01_rev0\Core.PowershellModule.TradeLoader.dll' was
>   not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module
>   directory.

because files are in server B

Comment: `C:\ ` is the server's local disc. `C:\ ` doesn't mean *"somehow infer what server I am talking about and look at C for that server"*. You'll need to use the full UNC path, however, I doubt your SQL Server service account has access to the desktop on your machine (nor should it), so you'll need to place it in a share that  the share does have access to. I also, however, don't recommend having `xp_cmdshell` being able to run executables located on another computer; that seems like a disaster waiting to happen. Really this seems like an XY problem. What are you *really* trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 0):

I am running sql scripts stored in files (sqlscript.sql)  on ServerA against a SQL installation on ServerB using remote powershell. The Powershel module SQLPS is needed on serverA.
[see link](http://#https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017)

steps:

1. enable remotepowershell on serverB

   Enable-PSRemoting -force
2. in your SQL server, add the user that executes the script on serverA in the list of users with rights on the database.
3. use a script on severA like:

   Import-Module -Name SQLPS -NoClobber -DisableNameChecking -Scope Local Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance serverA -InputFile sqlscript.sql
   -Verbose

   Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance 'serverB' -InputFile sqlscript.sql -Verbose